# ./Configure GPhoto2 Error: libgphoto2 requires libltdl (the libtool dl* library)

Tags: installation

I wanted to play with GPhoto2, but when I run `./configure`, I got following error:

> libgphoto2 requires libltdl (the libtool dl* library)

When I tried to install libtool-ltdl, it says it has been installed already.

Answer (score 1):

instead of libtool-ltdl, libtool-ltdl-devel is needed as it is for development purpose.

install libtool-ltdl-devel by following command:

```
sudo yum install libtool-ltdl-devel
```

now, ./configure runs well